# How to get the log from an application deployed using docker on AWS ecs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, console.log, amazon-ecs

I have a backend application running on `node.js` with `feathers.js` framework. I have deployed it using **docker** and it is currently maintained by **AWS ECS**.

In my application, I have a few lines of `'console.log'` to display some Strings for debugging purposes. I am wondering when I have deployed the application on AWS ECS, where is `console.log` printed to and how do I access it?

Answer (score 5):

**You have to create a log group on ECS:**

Follow these steps to create your log group-

**Step 1:** Open the Amazon ECS console at `https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/`.

**Step 2:** In the left navigation pane, choose **Task Definitions**, **Create new Task Definition.**

**Step 3:** Choose your `compatibility option` and then Next Step.

**Step 4:** Choose `Add container` to begin creating your container definition.

**Step 5:** In the `Storage and Logging section`, for Log configuration choose `Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs`.

**Step 6:** Enter your `awslogs log driver options`. For more details, see [Specifying a Log Configuration in your Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html#specify-log-config).

**Step 7:** Complete the rest of the task definition wizard.

**After creating your log view you can see it by using below steps:**

**Step 1:** Open the CloudWatch console at `https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/`.

**Step 2:** In the navigation pane, **choose Logs**.

**Step 3:** For Log Groups, **choose the log group** to view the streams.

**Step 7:** For Log Streams, choose the `log stream name` to **view the log data.**

For more details:

[Working with Log Groups and Log Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html)

[Using the awslogs Log Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your container definition you need to mention the log configuration. Since Its unclear whether you are creating the ecs cluster using cloudformation / from gui console, I will try to answer for both ways.

**1. GUI console:**

[image: AWS Log Configuration In Task definition]

**2. Using cloudformation template:**

```
    {
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nodejsApplication",
            "links": [
                "mysql"
            ],
            "image": "nodejsApplication",
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-nodejsApplication",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
                }
            },
            "memory": 500,
            "cpu": 10
        }
     ]
    }
```

For more details please follow [Using Awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` prints to STDOUT. A good way to collect this as logs is to [use the awslogs log driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html). This will route those logs to a CloudWatch Logs stream of your choice. Here is more [information on what CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) and how you can use it.